# Динамическое генерирование inline кнопок при создании телеграм бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, python-telegram-bot

Делаю телеграм бота через telebot
У меня есть сайт и с него через парсинг берутся данные
После парсинга получаю данные:
Адрес: ул. Балканская, 26
Адрес: ул. Ратная, 27
Мне необходимо создавать inline кнопки в зависимости от полученных значений после парсинга. Эти значения могут быть разными и создавать кнопки надо динамически. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Получаете все данные, откуда Вы там их берёте. Проходите по ним циклом и строите кнопки.

Comment: Можно пример? 
Мне нужно понять как организовать цикл и как их строить. Данные у меня выводятся сообщением вот так 
`for i in range(0, len(adress)):
       bot.send_message(cid, f'{adress[i].text}')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from telebot.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton

keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
keyboard.row_width = 2

for i in range(0, len(adress)):
    keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(adress[i].text, callback_data="address_"))

bot.send_message(cid,'Выберите адрес парковки',reply_markup = keyboard)
```

Вам только нужно изменить под себя `callback_data` (ID адреса, например, или что там у Вас) и при отправке сообщения (`bot.send_message()`) в аргументе reply_markup передавать переменную keyboard.

Comment: Почему выводиться 2 раза? Код:        `keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        keyboard.row_width = 2
        for i in range(0, len(adress)):
            keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(adress[i].text, callback_data="address_"))
            bot.send_message(cid,'Выберите адрес парковки',reply_markup = keyboard)` Скрин:https://imgur.com/a/nbdKnWd

Comment: @Иван потому что вы отправляете сообщение в цикле. Обновил ответ для Вас.

Comment: Спасибо большое. А как мне теперь обработать нажатие? Мне необходимо как-то обрабатывать нажатие и получать текст выбранной кнопки. У меня же всегда callback_data будет разная

Comment: Создайте обработчик, получайте айди нажатой кнопки и делайте то, что нужно :) вот пример из документации: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/inline_keyboard_example.py

Answer (score 0):

В [данном посте](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51904640/16984927) очень подробно описана генерация кнопок. Когда каждой call.data присваивается префикс, а при нажатии делается выборка по данному префиксу методом call.data.startswith. И далее с этим можно удобно работать

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/737794)